# Redirect URL to a Subdomain by .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect a URL to a subdomain 
I am already redirecting form a  old domain to a new domain 
Like http://abc.com to http://xyz.com by the below code

```
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 / http://xyz.com/
```

So my Url becomes http://xyz.com/blog/

Now I want to redirect http://abc.com/blog/ to http://blog.xyz.com

How can I do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to turn the rewrite engine on, as the `Redirect` directive is part of mod_alias. You can add the other redirect *before* the one that redirects to `xyz.com`:

```
Redirect 301 /blog/ http://blog.xyz.com/

Redirect 301 / http://xyz.com/
```