# How can I write a redirect rule to send traffic to a subdomain?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect requests to the URL:

```
example.com/downloads
```

to

```
download.example.com/downloads
```

How can I write a regex rule for this for an .htaccess file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect URL to a Subdomain by .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758245/redirect-url-to-a-subdomain-by-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

[You don't actually need `mod_rewrite` to do this.](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/WhenNotToUseRewrite) Nor do you need a regex, unless you're matching a *pattern* instead of just a string.

```
Redirect ^/downloads http://download.example.com/downloads
```

If you need to match a pattern (i.e. redirect each subdirectory to a subdomain - sounds like a bad idea to me, but whatever) then you *do* need a regex, but you still don't need `mod_rewrite`.

```
RedirectMatch ^/([^/+])(/.+)? http://$1.example.com/$1$2
```

This matches a string immediately following the domain, i.e. the "downloads" part of `http://example.com/downloads/somefile`, then any trailing part of the request, and builds an URL to redirect to using those two pieces.

Answer (score 0):

Place this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^downloads(/.*)?$ http://download.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L,NC]
```